# ¿Cómo tener un id serial en grails?

Tags: grails

Necesito saber como asignar un id a una clase de dominio que no sea `bigint` como lo genera el grails. ¿Necesito que el tipo de dato sea `serial`? ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? He probado con esto pero no ha funcionado:

```
        static mapping = {
     id generator: 'assigned', name: "id", type:'serializable'
     }
```

Comment: Que motor de base de datos estás utilizando? Podrías mencionar, simplemente por curiosidad, por qué necesitas que sea del tipo mencionado?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo muy similar pero con `sqlType` en vez de `type`. Algo así como:

```
  static mapping = {
     id generator: 'assigned', name: "id", sqlType:'serializable'
  }
```